# Windows 10 SDK browser control

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Any one knows about the BrowserCOntrol available as a part of windows 10 SDK is the same like in previous versions or a new control?
Is any impact of the new brwoser control from windows on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on the new Microsoft Edge rendering engine on Windows 10. You can learn more about it from the Microsoft Virtual Academy video series on Windows 10 development.

Here's a link to the video series:

- https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-12618

You can jump straight to the Module 9 video "Microsoft Edge and the Web Platform", although I would recommend that you make time to watch the entire video series.

Below is a screenshot from the video that says that the new WebView control uses the "always current" Edge rendering engine. This implies that the browser engine used by an app is always the same version as the Edge browser available in the OS, which will continue to receive updates as configured.

[image]

> SCREENSHOT: snapshot of MVA video on Win10 dev, Module 9, 0:33.13

Hope that helps!